# PnPJS - MS Graph API - how to get group photo

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp, microsoft-graph

I am using [PnPJS](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/graph/docs/) for MS Graph API to retrieve groups information in SPFx solution. 
I am able to get the groups information properly. I need to get the group photo also, since photo is not available in the first request while getting the groups info, I am doing one more call. But I am not sure how to use this returned object as image. I am doing as below

```
private getGroupPhoto(groupId:string):Promise<any>{
   return this.props.graphContext.groups.getById(groupId).photo.get().then((k)=>{
    return k;
   }) as Promise<any>;
  }
```

Above code is returning me below output

```
@odata.context: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('339492f5-c1cb-4b1e-904e-d39099601f12')/photo/$entity"
@odata.mediaContentType: "image/jpeg"
@odata.mediaEtag: ""59E3A994""
height: 648
id: "648X648"
width: 648
```

How to use this as image in html?

Edited: 
When I use the `photo.getBlob` method then output as follows
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getBlob` method to get the image bytes as blob and then bind that to the HTML element somewhat as below. If you know a different way, you can use that as well:

```
private getGroupPhoto(groupId:string):Promise<any>{
   return this.props.graphContext.groups.getById(groupId).photo.getBlob().then((k)=>{

    let groupPhotoUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    let blobUrl = groupPhotoUrl.createObjectURL(k);
    document.querySelector("#image").src = blobUrl;

   }) as Promise<any>;
  }
```

or as below:

```
private getGroupPhoto(groupId:string):Promise<any>{
   return this.props.graphContext.groups.getById(groupId).photo.getBlob().then((k)=>{

    var arr = new Uint8Array(k);

        //  Don't use fromCharCode.apply as it blows the stack with moderate size images
        var raw = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            raw = raw + String.fromCharCode(arr[i]);
        }
        var b64 = window.btoa(raw);
        var blobUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b64;
        document.querySelector("#image").src = blobUrl;

   }) as Promise<any>;
  }
```

Reference - [Microsoft Graph REST API - Get photo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[Embed Group Photo from Microsoft Graph API into Web page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982335/862892)

Comment: what is url object here? you mean `window.URL`?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: check edited post as well for 2nd alternative and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27737668/862892) link as well !

Comment: first option was worked. `createObjectURL` did magic. I didn't know this. This is working fine in local workbench, this will work for production version also right!

Comment: Yes will work on prod as well